# How to check if join was 1-1 or 1-many in SAS?

Tags: join, sas

Is there an efficient way in SAS to verify if a join you ran was a 1 to 1 or a 1 to many join? I often work with tables that do not have a clear unique identifier which has led me to running 1-many joins thinking they were 1-1, thus messing up my analysis.

Comment: Join in `merge` or join in `proc sql`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN=` flags, but you need to clear them.

Let's make some sample datasets.

```
data one; 
  do id=1,2,2,3; 
    output; 
  end; 
run;

data two; 
  do id=1,1,2,2,3,3; 
    output; 
  end; 
run;
```

Now merge them by ID.  Clear the IN= variables before the MERGE statement so that the flag is not carried forward on the dataset with just a single observation.

```
data want ;
  call missing(in1,in2);
  merge one(in=in1) two (in=in2);
  by id;
  if not first.id and sum(of in1-in2)> 1 then put 'Multiple Merge: ' (_n_ id in1 in2) (=);
run;
```

Results in the LOG.

```
Multiple Merge: _N_=4 id=2 in1=1 in2=1
NOTE: MERGE statement has more than one data set with repeats of BY values.
NOTE: There were 4 observations read from the data set WORK.ONE.
NOTE: There were 6 observations read from the data set WORK.TWO.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 6 observations and 1 variables.
```

Comment: Looks to me like that nifty approach identifies keys that were in a many-to-many merge, but I think OP wants to catch even a one-to-many merge (id=3 in sample data).

Comment: It is so easy to detect 1 to many (not first.id) that it did occur to me that someone would need to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case where I'm expecting the input datasets for a merge to be unique by some key, I will often code a simple assertion into the merge that throws an error if any duplicates are found:

Sample data:

```
data one; 
  do id=1,2,3;
    output;
  end;
run;

data two;
  do id=1,2,2,3,4,4;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Log:

```
16   data want;
17     merge one two;
18     by id;
19     if not (first.id and last.id) then put "ERROR: duplicates!" id=;
20   run;

ERROR: duplicates!id=2
ERROR: duplicates!id=2
ERROR: duplicates!id=4
ERROR: duplicates!id=4
NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.ONE.
NOTE: There were 6 observations read from the data set WORK.TWO.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 6 observations and 1 variables
```

That doesn't tell you which dataset has duplicates (for that you need to use in= variables like Tom's answer), but it's an easy safety net to catch duplicates.

You can also just check your output dataset for duplicates after the merge, e.g.

```
data _null_;
  set want (keep=id);
  by id;
  if not (first.id and last.id) then put "ERROR: Duplicate ! " id=;
run;
```

Duplicates are dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Checking **before** merging is a better idea... Here are two nice and easy ways to do it. (Supposing we have a dataset named `one` with column `id` to be used for the merge).

### Identify duplicate id's with `PROC FREQ`

```
proc freq data = one noprint;
  table id /out = freqs_id_one(where=(count>1));
run;
```

### Sort dataset using `nodupkey`

...redirecting duplicate id's in a distinct dataset:

```
proc sort data=one nodupkey out=one_nodupids dupout=one_dupids;
  by id;
run;
```

---

### Checking *after-the-fact*

If you realize too late that you didn't check for dupes (doh!), you can obtain the frequencies of the id with `PROC FREQ` (same code as above) or with a `PROC SQL` query:

```
proc sql;
  select id, 
         count(id) as count 
    from merged_dataset
      group by id
      having count > 1;
quit;
```